# Change in CSS the background-color for the first rect in my #ID

Tags: css, svg

I generate a SVG in a GWT application and I want to modify the first rect background-color inside my SVG in CSS.

Here the code:

```
<svg id="chart8" width="720" height="350" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <defs id="defs">...</defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="720" height="350" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">
  <g>...</g>
  <g><rect .../></g>
  <g>...</g>
</svg>
```

So i want to modify in CSS the fill value only for the first rect element for #chart8.

I tested this but it's not working:

```
#chart8 rect:first-of-type {
  fill: #F1F1F1;*/
}
```

Have you an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: please share full code

Comment: Are there other rect elements which are direct children of svg or are they all nested? In the given code `#chart8 > rect` would do

Comment: you haven't added `viewBox` attribute in SVG.

Comment: :first-of-type will select first-of-type at every level, nested tag. I understand you want to do `#chart8 > rect:first-of-type` or even `#chart8 > rect` if there's only rect at this nest level..

Comment: #chart8 > rect It's working, thanks!

And thanks for #chart8 > rect:first-of-type :-)